# Django-nonrel can't login as super user

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I"ve done such commands

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

If I do `python manage.py runserver`

In this case I can login, and I can see the user I created.

While if I use GAE's SDK to start the server, I canNOT log in. Why?

Answer (score 2):

This might be the problem:

You have setup a database for a normal django project.
So `manage.py createsuperuser` will create a superuser in that database.

In case of GAE SKD, it uses the `GAE Datastore`, so the superuser you created is not present there.

This is what you could do:

- Create a normal user
- Go to `/_ah/admin/` and modify the data for user table in datastore, changing the desired users is_superuser field to `True`.

Comment: you will need to create at least one user first....create one through your site's normal registration system....then you will see the models in the datastore.

Answer (score 1):

From the [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#management-commands) page:

> Important: Don't use dev_appserver.py directly. This won't work as expected because manage.py runserver uses a customized dev_appserver.py configuration

Answer (score 0):

**aardvax** posted great link. But in case no one goes into it. The answer is to create users **remotely**

creating superuser:

```
manage.py remote createsuperuser
```

using remote shell (to use User api):

```
manage.py remote shell
```

Hope it helps.