# Django-nonrel can't login as super user to localhost admin site

Tags: google-app-engine, django-admin, django-nonrel

I got the django-nonrel setup fine, and worked through the first 5 chapters of the djangobook without any real problems. I'm currently on chapter 6 which talks about creating the admin site. http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06/ But, I can't login.

I can get to the admin login page on localhost, but it always says my username and password are incorrect.

Some suggest to "Go into your database and inspect the auth_user table. Make sure that is_staff is set to TRUE on the user you are using to log in." I went into here: "python manage.py shell" And saw that my superuser was there, and that is_staff was true.

I created a superuser with the server running and without it running, and neither one allowed me to login afterwords.

One user (crogjer) suggested the following:

> This might be the problem:
>
> You have setup a database for a normal django project.
>   So manage.py createsuperuser will create a superuser in that database.
>
> In case of GAE SKD, it uses the GAE Datastore, so the superuser you created is not present >there.
>
> This is what you could do:
>
> Create a normal user
>   Go to /_ah/admin/ and modify the data for user table in datastore, changing the desired >users is_superuser field to True.

What is the SKD? Does that sound like the answer to my problems? If so, how do I create a normal user?

Here are some of the reference posts I saw:
I've looked around at the following posts:
[Can't login to Django /admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751434/cant-login-to-django-admin-interface)
[django-nonrel google app engine fail to log in admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686060/django-nonrel-google-app-engine-fail-to-log-in-admin-panel)
[Django-nonrel can't login as super user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836054/django-nonrel-cant-login-as-super-user)

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Not really a solution, but running this from a view will allow me to create an admin user:  User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, admin) .  Thr problem seems to be that the management console and the local dev server don't use the same datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I was running the server through the GoogleAppEngineLauncher when it wasn't working, and I just needed to stop the local server, create the super user, and then run it through

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Surely this wasn't obvious to me too! Run `./manage.py createsuperuser` then next use the `./manage runserver`

Comment: I tried everything here, it seems to create the users but doesn't let me log into the localhost admin. Works on the deployed application.

Comment: I also had the same problem. It worked when I stopped the server and created the superuser again. Thanks b-ryce